# how to remove all documents from a collection except one in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way to remove all the documents except one from a collection based on condition.

I am using MongoDB version 2.4.9

Comment: You should gave us an example of your documents. Perhaps it could be faster to save the document, drop the collection and insert the document saved back.

Comment: or using negative condition in remove
 db.inventory.remove( { qty: { $ne: 20 } } )
this will remove all document other that one which matches qty=20

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can do this in below way,

```
db.inventory.remove( { type : "food" } )
```

Above query will remove documents with type equals to "food"

To remove document that not matches condition you can do,

```
db.inventory.remove( { type : { $ne: "food" } } )
```

or

```
db.inventory.remove( { type : { $nin: ["Apple", "Mango"] } } )
```

Check [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-documents/#remove-documents-that-match-a-condition) for more info.

Comment: UPDATED version: db.getCollection("COLLECTION_NAME").deleteMany( { "COLUMN_NAME" : { $nin: ["VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3"] } } )

Answer (score 7):

To remove all documents except one, we can use the query operator `$nin` (not in) over a specified array containing the values related to the documents that we want to keep.

```
db.collections.remove({"field_name":{$nin:["valueX"]}})
```

The advantage of `$nin` array is that we can use it to delete all documents except one or two or even many other documents.

To delete all documents except two:

```
db.collections.remove({"field_name":{$nin:["valueX", "valueY"]}})
```

To delete all documents except three:

```
db.collections.remove({"field_name":{$nin:["valueX", "valueY", "valueZ"]}})
```

Answer (score 4):

Query

```
db.collection.remove({ "fieldName" : { $ne : "value"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above by Taha EL BOUFFI, the following worked for me.

```
db.collection.remove({"fieldName" : { $nin: ["value"]}});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31194282)